# One of my pygame screens is running 2 times when I import a function that returns 2 variables from another file

Tags: python, function, pygame, return

I have a pygame project, which I have divided into 3 different screens: initial screen, game screen and play again screen. On the game screen I want to return the state of the game as well as the highscore so that I can show it on the play again screen. But my game screen is running twice before going do the play again screen.

```
# Game Loop

state = INIT
while state != DONE:
    if state == INIT:
        state, highscore = init_screen(screen)
    elif state == PLAYING:
        state, highscore = game_screen(screen)
    elif state == PLAYAGAIN:
        state = play_again(screen)
    else:
        state = DONE
```

```
# What game screen returns

return state, highscore
```

```
#What I'm using in the play again screen to get the highscore from the game screen

highscore = game_screen(screen)[1]
```

```
hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, world_sprites, True, pygame.sprite.collide_mask)

        if len(hits) > 0:
            if score > highscore:
                highscore = score
            state = PLAYAGAIN
```

This last code should make the game screen go to the play again screen, which was working before I decided to put highscores.

Btw, where should I put the first value for to highscore (highscore = 0)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call the game_screen() function during your play_again() function. This runs the game_screen() function, which would explain why you are seeing the game run twice. I would suggest storing your highscore in a global variable then using that in your play_again() function, rather than getting if from your game_screen() function:

```
state, highscore = INIT, 0
while state != DONE:
    ...
```

Then in your play_again() function, get rid of the line that says:

```
highscore = game_screen()[1]
```

And instead simply say:

```
global highscore
```

Comment: I think it worked, thank you! Just one more thing, how can I import the highscore from one file to another if I'm not returning it in the file that I'm exporting it from?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean- If you write the high score to a file then it will be in the file whether you retrieve it again or not. Then you can access that file from any other script you want.